# Property Modifiers

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have classes structured like this:

```
Public MustInherit Class A
  ' several properties
End Class

Public Class B
  Inherits A
  ' several properties
End Class

Public MustInherit Class C
  Protected _X As A
  Public ReadOnly Property X As A
    Get
      Return _X
    End Get
  End Property
End Class

Public Class D
  Inherits C
  Private _X As B
  Public ReadOnly Property X As B
    Get
      Return _X
    End Get
  End Property
  Sub New
    _X = New B
  End Sub
End Class
```

Is there a modifier I can use on property X in class D which will cause X to be returned as B from an instance of D and A from an instance of D that is evaluated as C?

i.e.

```
Dim d As New D
Response.Write((d.X Is Nothing) & "<br>")
Dim c As C = d
Response.Write(c.X Is Nothing)
```

In both cases I want X to not be Nothing

I realize I could modify D as follows:

```
Public Class D
  Inherits C
  Private __X As B
  Public ReadOnly Property X As B
    Get
      Return __X
    End Get
  End Property
  Sub New
    __X = New B
    _X = __X
  End Sub
End Class
```

Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: I haven't tried it my self, but I believe if you actually compile this code you'll be told to specify `Shadows` or you need to change `C`'s `X` to `Overridable`. I haven't checked but I _think_ `Shadows` will do what you want.

Comment: You're right about the compiler - it says to use `Overloads` but it's happy with `Shadows` as well.  Unfortunately, neither one solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid new code using `Shadows`, but if you really need this construct, I get the results you're expecting with just the addition of `MyBase._X=_X` to `D`'s `New` (*Option 1*) which could also be done by having a `New` in `C` that `D` calls, then does the opposite assignment `_X = DirectCast(MyBase._X, B)` (*Option 2*).

Of course another option, depending upon your actual intention, is to drop the `Private _X As B` in `D` and just cast the `_X` to `B` in your shadowed `X`. (*Option 3*)

Here is my code with *Options 1 and 2* commented out and currently performing *Option 3*.

```
Public MustInherit Class C
    Protected _X As A
    ''Option 2:
    'Protected Sub New(X As A)
    '    _X = X
    'End Sub
    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property X As A
        Get
            Return _X
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class D
    Inherits C
    'Commented out for option 3:
    'Private Shadows _X As B
    Public Shadows ReadOnly Property X As B
        Get
            'Commented out for option 3:
            'Return _X
            Return DirectCast(_X, B)
        End Get
    End Property
    Sub New()
        ''Option 1,3: (Comment out for option 2)
        _X = New B
        ''Option 1:
        'MyBase._X = _X
        ''Option 2:
        'MyBase.New(New B)
        '_X = DirectCast(MyBase._X, B)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I didn't test all the options but I think only Option 2 will work.  Basically, if I store a B as an A and then recast it to a B, I would lose any B properties in the process.  Option 2 is cleaner than what I came up with - thanks!

Comment: @ic3b3rg You say "if I store a `B` as an `A` and then recast it to a `B`, I would lose any `B` properties in the process": It is only a cast, the object is still really a `B`; its properties are still there. It is just a feature of `Shadows` (and `Overrides` when available), and what your main question was asking for, that allows variations in what you see through the `A` class to a `B` object.